# Python: Iterating through a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, iterator

I am given a text file that contains many lines like the following... many random information

> Spiaks Restaurant|42.74|-73.70|2 Archibald St+Watervliet, NY 12189|http://www.yelp.com/biz/spiaks-restaurant-watervliet|Italian|4|5|4|3|3|4|4

For example, Spiaks Restaurant is in position 0, 42.74 is in position 1, -73.70 is in position 2.... Italian is in position 5... 
4|5|4|3|3|4|4 is another list... so basically a list within a list, and the number 4 would be in position 6, 5 in position 7.. etc

I have to ask the user, and the user should reply with:

```
What type of restaurant would you like => Italian
What is the minimum rating => 3.6
```

The result should be:

```
Name: Spiaks Restaurant; Rating 3.86
Name: Lo Portos; Rating 4.00
Name: Verdiles Restaurant; Rating 4.00
Found 3 restaurants.
```

Here is my code:

```
rest_type = raw_input("What type of restaurant would you like => ")
min_rate = float(raw_input("What is the minimum rating => "))

def parse_line(text_file):
count = 0.0
a_strip = text_file.strip('\n')
b_split = a_strip.split('|')

for i in range(6, len(b_split)):
    b_split[i] = int(b_split[i]) # Takes the current indices in the list and converts it to integers
    count += b_split[i] # Add up all of the integers values to get the total ratings
    avg_rate = count/len(b_split[6:len(b_split)]) # Takes the total ratings & divides it by the length

#The above basically calculates the average of the numbers like 4|5|4|3|3|4|4

    if (rest_type == b_split[5] and avg_rate >= min_rate):
        print b_split[0], avg_rate
```

The problem with the result is.. I get:

```
None
```

I know this is a very, very long question, but if someone could give me some insight, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you trying printing out all of the information you aggregated?

Find out where the error is occurring, be it when you try to parse for specific restaurants, or you just straight up parse nothing and end up with a blank list.